Postgres Npgsql Connection Pooling in a Microservice Stack with Tenant-Databases
we have a microservice stack with a multi tenant system.
At the moment we have 5 "heavy" requested services with around 1000 customers / tenants, each having one database.
Now we start to hit the connection pooling limit, because it is set to 100 (we increased to 200 or 300, but it's allways just a temporary fix).
The problem is, that with the default settings:
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#pooling
it seems pooling a bad idea here in generel - yes, I know why pooling is here, but in fact each customer has it's own connectionstring, means its own connection, means on 1000 customers with ~2500 users, means pooling itself might be a "bad" thing for us.
Is there any general information / whitepaper / idea about the concept of how to handle pooling / db connections in a microservice multi tenant application?

I am not aware of any general information. However your use case is one where the default connection pooling approach is likely to be a problem as each distinct connection string will lead to a separate connection pool. (Because the common use case is one connection string the default operation optimised for this. Like anything, if you are building an edge case the defaults are going to be wrong for you some of the time.)

When considering multi-tenant and the decision between using discriminators (multiple tenants per database) and database/schema per tenant it comes down to how you want to scale. Tenant-per-database (or a mix /w tenants-per-database) is about pure isolation and enabling horizontal scalability, supporting spinning up new database instances when you hit a threshold. It sounds like with PostgreSQL you are taking advantage of a Schema-per-Tenant, which would be like a DB-per-Tenant in SQL Server and the issue is that you have 1000+ Schemas on a single database server. Consider capping your database/schema number to suite the connection limit for the server hardware and spin up a new database instance for another set of schemas.
This may require a bit of a design shift for handling initial authentication. The designs I have used involve having one central authentication server (with fail-over) which the applications/services all talk to initially. This data contains global information about the system, as well as any versioning/licensing/config about the tenants. Each tenant then receives their "data" connection string details associated with their account and their application/service spins up their connection to their data pointing to their designated server instance. That connection information is cached, such as in session state for web services, as well as additional details like messaging such as upcoming maintenance windows, etc. so the services can inform the client users or periodically poll the central Auth DB for status updates. This allows me to perform maintenance on tenant databases, moving them if necessary and updating their centralized config to point them at the new database as scaling or servicing needs change. (I.e. to balance tenants on hardware as some sites are bigger consumers than others, especially after an evaluation period)
Connection pooling on the authentication database will work as normal as all tenants share the same connection string, and access to this server/schema is brief. Tenants can share a database server for their individual schemas/databases and have a reasonable number of instances per server to keep the server happy with any pooling or concurrent connection requests in general. These database server instances can still scale vertically as tenants fill the server. At the start, the authentication server can host tenant databases so you don't need to initially pay for a dedicated extra database server, but as you grow you can spin up a 2nd database server instance and migrate tenants during a maintenance window or via a replication and fail-over model for less disruption if it is a 24/7 service.
Hopefully that might give you some ideas for a solution.
